# QA Tool / Framework to run kdb scripts

Tags: testing, kdb

I am new to "KDB DATA testing" & I would like to build (Test scenario based) scripts using q programming language. Each test scenario is associated to each .q file. Is there any existing framework / tool which I can use to run these .q files & generate the report for the same ?

Please let me know, if you have any relevant information on this.

Comment: What have you already done to find out your question yourself?

Comment: We have written wrapper(Shell scripts) around these q files which runs these q files sequentially.  Our main focus is to use some tools which will run these q files and generates summary reports in graphical format. The way we get it in other automation tools.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1):

[qStudio](http://www.timestored.com/qstudio/) from Timestored also supports unit testing, though the output is not graphical. See here: [qUnit](http://www.timestored.com/qstudio/#qUnit)

Comment: There is a new HTML report that provides a visual diff of actual and expected values: http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-regression-unit-tests#test-report

Answer (score -1):

Simon Garland's k4unit may be similar to what you're looking for:

https://github.com/simongarland/k4unit

Alternatively, Daniel Nugent has another unit testing framework:

https://github.com/nugend/qspec

Kx Systems also maintains the following list of Git repos, which is generally the first place to look if you're trying to find something along these lines:

https://kxsystems.github.io/

Comment: Thanks Paul , I will have a look at the shared links. We are looking for UI tool which will invoke our script files and generate the report in graphical format like other tools generate.

Comment: Ah, if you're looking for a graphical interface the simplest to configure is probably Q Server for R (You can find an explanation here: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/IntegratingWithR#Connecting_from_R_to_kdb.2B_.28a.k.a._Q_Server_for_R.29 ). This will still require some work, however - I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box testing suite for kdb+ that comes equipped with a prebuilt GUI.